# Alexa APL input using built-in keyboard

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I have an Echo Spot and I'm using Alexa Presentation Language (APL) to implement the user interface. I want to have user input by using the built-in keyboard. Is it possible to invoke the built-in keyboard in Node.js SDK?

[image]

Comment: I don't think for now there is no keyboard access for custom skills. But this is requested feature see (https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33633652-echo-show-keyboard-access-for-custom-skill)

Comment: It seems like I have to build my custom input keyboard with other components...